# How often should I have my server sync to the database?

Tags: database

I am developing a web-app right now, where clients will frequently (every few seconds), send read/write requests on certain data. As of right now, I have my server immediately write to the database when a user changes something, and immediately read from the database when they want to view something. This is working fine for me, but I am guessing that it would be quite slow if there were thousands of users online.

Would it be more efficient to save write requests in an object on the server side, then do a bulk update at a certain time interval? This would help in situations where the same data is edited multiple times, since it would now only require one db insert. It would also mean that I would read from the object for any data that hasn't yet been synced, which could mean increased efficiency by avoiding db reads. At the same time though, I feel like this would be a liability for two reasons: 1. A server crash would erase all data that hasn't yet been synced. 2. A bulk insert has the possibility of creating sudden spikes of lag due to mass database calls.

How should I approach this? Is my current approach ok, or should I queue inserts for a later time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user makes a change to data and takes an action that (s)he expects will save the data, you should do everything you can to ensure the data is actually saved.  Example: Let's say you delay the write for a while.  The user is in a hurry, makes a change then closes the browser.  If you don't save right when they take an action that they expect saves the data, there would be a data loss.

Web stacks generally scale horizontally.  Don't start to optimize this kind of thing unless there's evidence that you really have to.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a client side queue though; I am suggesting that I use websockets to send over the read/write request, and queue it on the server side. This would mean that even if the client closed their browser, the data would not be lost.

Comment: My comment about premature optimization still stands :-)  You introduce a lot of complexity queuing and merging changes to solve a problem that probably does not exist, or can be solved much less expensively by slightly upgrading hardware.  Also, unless you're using a transactional queue on the web server end, you still risk losing data if the web server goes down or recycles.  In a web farm, you would have to ensure that there's either a global queue, or that changes from a given client always go to the same server so you can merge changes.  Lots of complexity...

Comment: Do the majority of high-traffic sites simply do immediate reads/write to their databases? I am curious what the accepted standard is.

Comment: @Ari: High traffic websites often use a distributed cache to reduce the read burden (e.g. memcached, ehcache... which can also manage writes), or use a horizontally scalable data storage solution such as MongoDB.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for being patient with me. I'll accept your answer now :)